# How to read a CSV file with a date and time with milliseconds? ('DD.MM.YYY hh:mm:ss:mmm')

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I have a CSV file with timestamps that have (empty) milliseconds in them (`01.01.1901 00:00:00:000`) and pandas ´read_csv´ can't seem to parse them:

test.csv:

```
date,value
18.03.2019 00:00:00:000,3.97
19.06.2019 00:00:00:000,4.22
10.09.2019 00:00:00:000,4.4
16.12.2019 00:00:00:000,5.6
```

`testdf = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=0, header=0, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True)`

```
testdf.index
Index(['18.03.2019 00:00:00:000', '19.06.2019 00:00:00:000',
       '10.09.2019 00:00:00:000', '16.12.2019 00:00:00:000'],
       dtype='object', name='date')
```

Obviously, I don't want that to be `'object'`, but `'datetime64[ns]'`, as I'd get when remove the empty time data by hand beforehand. How do I specify to `read_csv` how the time in my index column is formatted? Normally, it's pretty good at parsing dates, so it seems very odd to me that it's totally thrown of by the milliseconds, which is not that rare of a time format.

Comment: `format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S:%f"` should do the trick in your case. With pandas v2, use the `date_format` kwarg of [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: The problem isn't the milliseconds. The file is using a custom and unusual format. Milliseconds use `.` as a separator, not `:`. I suspect `18.03.2019 00:00:00.000` would work without problems. It would be a great idea to use the unambiguous ISO8601 format instead of a localized format anyway.

Comment: From the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

use `date_format`: "Format to use for parsing dates when used in conjunction with parse_dates. For anything more complex, please read in as object and then apply to_datetime() as-needed."

Also note documentation for `parse_dates` specifies "For non-standard datetime parsing, use to_datetime() after read_csv()."

You could also try infer_datetime_format, again see documentation linked

Comment: The linked question in the close and FObersteiner's comment did the trick. Seems like my search terms were wrong. "It would be a great idea to use...": Indeed. It would be even greater if that wretched CSV file this is from would follow any sane guidelines, but unfortunately, this is beyond my control.